# How to retrieve error message in HTTP4S client?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, http4s

I am trying to use Blaze client for http4s to make http calls. It works fine when 200 response is returned but in case of HTTP 500 or 400 I am not able to figure out how to retrieve the detailed error message returned from server.

I am can only see folllwing in the logs for this client.

> 2022-11-10 23:37:40 INFO  - Shutting down connection pool:
> curAllocated=1 idleQueues.size=1 waitQueue.size=0
> maxWaitQueueLimit=256 closed=false org.http4s.client.UnexpectedStatus:
> unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error

```
  def callEffect(client: Client[IO]): IO[String] = {
    val uri = serverUrl
      .withPath("/abc")
    val request = GET(uri, Accept(MediaType.application.json))

    client.expect[String](request).map { res =>
      println(res)
      res
    }
  }

  def deploy(implicit cs: ContextShift[IO]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    BlazeClientBuilder[IO](scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global).resource
      .map(x => println(callEffect(x).unsafeRunSync()))
      .use(_ => IO.unit.as(ExitCode.Success))
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the result is provided inside an `IO`, you can use any of `IO`'s error handling features to handle the issues, for example with `redeem`

```
def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    BlazeClientBuilder[IO].resource
      .use(client =>
        for {
          result <- callEffect(client).redeem(
            error => "could not get a result",
            something => s"this is what I got: $something"
          )
          _ <- IO.println(result)
        } yield ExitCode.Success
      )
  }
```

There's a great article on this topic here:
https://softwaremill.com/practical-guide-to-error-handling-in-scala-cats-and-cats-effect/

For even more control, you can handle errors from the client itself, for example using `expectOr()` instead of `expect()`, which gives you access to a convenient `onError: Response[F] => F[Throwable]`.

Answer (score 2):

We are handling errors from the http4s client this way:

```
    client
      .expect[T](Request[IO](Method.GET, uri)
      .handleError {
        case UnexpectedStatus(status, requestMethod, requestUri) => ??? 
        case error: Throwable => ???
      }
```

In the handle error there are more cases that you can have depending on your use case. For example based on your encoding you can have a `DecodeFailure` error.

Hope it helps.